# Duplicated mails when send to distribution group

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007

I have at least a user that have a old problem with duplicated mails, when it receives from a distribution group.

For example, when a **User 1** from the inside domain, send a mail to a Distribution **Group A** of the same domain, where a **User 2** is, this last user will receive two mails.

The first one is the original, where it cames as expected. The second one, is the original one, forwarded with the same heather, but with the list of the distribution group:

[image]

Note: this User 2 is classified as an administrator of this server.

Server Specs:

- Windows SBS 2008
- Exchange 2007

UPDATE 1:

Windows SBS 2008 is installed in my smart host, who is connected with my remote mail server, where i can config through cpanel. Forwarding at cpanel, means forward to another email account and it saves a copy at original destination.

In my remote mail server i have those forwardings:

User 0 -> **Group A**

**User 1** -> **Group A**

User 3 -> **Group A**

User 4 -> **User 2**

User 5 -> **User 2**

And in my smart host:

**Group A** -> **User 2**, User n, ...

Comment: Just to clarify, which user is the administrator and when you say the "Last user will receive two emails" do you mean that all members of the group receive 2 emails?

Comment: thanks for the response, the administrator is the User 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that this is not a simple forwarding, this is a **journal report**, who forward mails from a certain configured user to another, with a list of all the stackholders in each mail, and it can be created or disable through:

Exchange Management Console >> Organization Configuration >> Hub Transport >> Jounaling

Answer (score 1):

Being an administrator of the server makes no difference.
The group system is intelligent, so if a user is a member of one or more groups, then they only get one copy. The only time that multiple copies are received is when the second (or more) copy is being delivered outside of the group system - ie a forward from another account. 
You need to look at the membership of the group, and then where this user gets email from - another account forwarded, delegate etc. That will be the cause.

That second header in your screenshot does not look like a header I have seen generated by Exchange/Outlook - suggesting the email is going out and then coming back in again.

Comment: Thank you for the response! But it was not supposed to receive mails from the distribution group without the distribution list in that mail? So i can assume that the first mail without that list, is the one forwarded from the user.

Comment: I have indeed some forwardings from three users to one distribution group being done in my remote mail server, coming from outside of the domain, and then it goes to my smart host where i have SBS 2008. There i have that distribution group with the same three users within others, like User 2.  In my smart host i dont have any forwarding from user to user, there i just have distribution groups. (i have also updated mu thread with this info!)

Comment: This has to be caused by what you are doing with the smart host. For whatever reason it is causing the emails to be forwarded back in again. 
In most instances Exchange should do all of the email handling - once something else gets involved then you can see problems like what you have seen already.